# Open Graph Cache with Like Button

Tags: facebook, caching

I have a problem with clearing LikeButton cache with Debugger tool. Debugger seems to clear only shared links cache but not liked cache.

Example:

```
http://czat.wp.pl/id_czata,3831,naszgosc.html
```

in the code of this page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.wp.pl/czat//zdcz/u/un/untitled1120.jpg" />
```

Debugger show right image:
https://s-external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDo_KKMFuh_-ZUT&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.wp.pl%2Fczat%2F%2Fzdcz%2Fu%2Fun%2Funtitled1120.jpg

But on my Wall (after liked the page) I have still wrong image (old one):
https://s-external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAdFogv-Fi4qFhd&w=290&h=290&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.wp.pl%2Fczat%2F%2Fzdcz%2Fs%2Fsy%2Fsylwia_mala1207055.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrzej: looks fine on both ends for me: Lint debugger and Screenshot from wall.

NOTE: **Your Like button seems to be liking a different page than the one you linked, you need to update the url for that button.**

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fczat.wp.pl%2Fid_czata%2C3831%2Cnaszgosc.html
```

[image]

Comment: Links share on the wall (your profile) works ok but the problem is with "what is on the wall when you like page by Like Button / Recommend Button" - when you click Like Button on site with material you want to share.

Comment: czat.wp.pl/id_czata,3831,title,Bozena-Batycka-i-Ewa-Dolowy,naszgosc.html  Your Recommend button is pointing to a different page.  Update the url to the current page.

Comment: Ow page is the same but url is different (one has optional parameter). Thank you for pointing that. Now it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this exact same problem also, our solution was to change the name of the page being liked by the linter because we could not get Facebook to update the cache for the Like button, even though the Lint Tool was showing the correct details for that page.